# Regex replacement capture followed by digit

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to get a Regex replacement working to update my AssemblyInfo.cs files, so I have:

```
Regex.Replace(
    contents, 
    @"(\[assembly: Assembly(File)?Version\("").*(""\)\])", 
    "$1" + version + "$3"
);
```

The problem is that `version` is something like `"1.5.3.0"`, so that when the replacement is evaluated it is seeing `"$11.5.3.0$3"` and is presumably looking for the eleventh captured group because it is coming out with:

```
$11.5.3.0")]
```

If is stick a space after the `$1` it works fine. What do I need to put in there to escape the  second digit without actually inserting the character?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `${1}` instead of `$1`. This is also the substitution syntax for named [capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx) `(?<name>)`.

Here's a snippet to illustrate ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4ebTD)):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("abc", "(.)", "$11"));        // $11$11$11
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("abc", "(.)", "${1}1"));      // a1b1c1
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("abc", "(?<x>.)", "${x}1"));  // a1b1c1
```

This behavior is explicitly documented:

> ### [Regular Expression Language Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) - [Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)
>
> #### [Substituting a Numbered Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#Numbered)
>
> The `$number` language element includes the last substring matched by the `number` capturing group in the replacement string, where `number` is the index of the capturing group.
>
> If `number` does not specify a valid capturing group defined in the regular expression pattern, `$number` is interpreted as a *literal character sequence* that is used to replace each match.
>
> #### [Substituting a Named Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#Named)
>
> The `${name}` language element substitutes the last substring matched by the `name` capturing group, where `name` is the name of a capturing group defined by the `(?<name>)` language element.
>
> If `name` does not specify a valid named capturing group defined in the regular expression pattern, `${name}` is interpreted as a *literal character sequence* that is used to replace each match.

Comment: Just using ${1} did it. Thanks!

Comment: `$[1}1` as numbered group works in `Powershell` as well.

Comment: How would you add a 1 to the whole string, not each char? In powershell, replacing each char and adding 1 to it is `write-host ($a -replace "(.)", '${1}1')`. I can repeat in the search param the string, but is there another option?

Comment: In Python, use `\g<1>` instead of `\1`.