# Why is "$1" ending up in my Regex.Replace() result?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to rewrite URLs to point to a proxy server.

```
bodystring = Regex.Replace(bodystring, "(src='/+)", "$1" + proxyStr);
```

The idea of this expression is pretty simple, basically find instances of "src='/" or "src='//" and insert a PROXY url at that point. This works in general but occasionally I have found cases where a literal "$1" will end up in the result string.

This makes no sense to me because if there was no match, then why would it replace anything at all?

Unfortunately I can't give a simple example of this at it only happens with very large strings so far, but I'd like to know conceptually what could make this sort of thing happen.

As an aside, I tried rewriting this expression using a positive lookbehind as follows:

```
bodystring = Regex.Replace(bodystring, "(?<=src='/+)", proxyStr);
```

But this ends up with proxyStr TWICE in the output if the input string contains "src='//". This also doesn't make much sense to me because I thought that "src=" would have to be present in the input twice in order to get proxyStr to end up twice in the output.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the `proxyStr` value?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please clarify? I'm not sure how I could use a "\1" to solve this problem. Above I meant that "$1" will sometimes end up in my result string, as in "...new Image().$1myproxy/proxy?url=.....".

Comment: proxyStr = "10.15.15.15:8008/proxy?url=http://"; However I have seen the second problem (multiple instances of proxyStr in the result) happen consistently even with proxyStr = "PROXY".

Comment: @Locksleyu What do you want to match? Your regex matches src='////////////////////////////////////. I am 99.99% sure that this is wrong.

Comment: FailedDev, you are right, the expression should have been "/{1,2}" instead of "/+". However when I replaced that everything was still the same, it doesn't fix my underlying issue.

Comment: Can you give a repro of this on ideone.com or somewhere ? I appreciate the text string has to be long to make it happen, but I think that's the only way you're going to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When `proxyStr = "10.15.15.15:8008/proxy?url=http://"`, the replacement string becomes `"$110.15.15.15:8008/proxy?url=http://"`. It contains a reference to group number 110, which certainly does not exist.

You need to make sure that your proxy string does not start in a digit. In your case you can do it by not capturing the last slash, and changing the replacement string to `"$1/"+proxyStr`, like this:

```
bodystring = Regex.Replace(bodystring, "(src='/*)/", "$1/" + proxyStr);
```

Edit:

Rawling [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466892/regex-replacement-capture-followed-by-digit) that .NET's regexp library addresses this issue: you can enclose `1` in curly braces to avoid false aliasing, like this:

```
bodystring = Regex.Replace(bodystring, "(src='/+)", "${1}" + proxyStr);
```

Comment: Rather than be cheeky and steal in with a proper solution - since you identified the problem first... see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466892/regex-replacement-capture-followed-by-digit Basically use "${1}" rather than "$1"

Comment: @Rawling Thanks for pointing this out! I suspected there must be a legitimate way of doing it, and even tried `($1)`, but I did not find the `${1}` answer. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing can't be done. .NET has trouble when interpolating variable like this. Your problem is that your Proxy string starts with a number : `proxyStr = "10.15.15.15:8008/proxy?url=http://"`

When you combine this with your `$1`, the regex thing it has to look for backreference `$110` which doesn't exist.

**[See what I mean here.](http://ideone.com/1I5Gi)**

You can remedy this by matching something else, or by matching and constructing the replacement string manually etc. Use what suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Based on dasblinkenlights answer (already +1) the solution is this:

```
bodystring = Regex.Replace(bodystring, "(src='/+)", "${1}" + proxyStr);
```

This ensures that the group 1 is used and not a new group number is build.

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, I guess proxyStr appears twice because you're inserting it once more. Try

```
string s2 = Regex.Replace(s, "((?<=src='/+))", proxyStr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried this and it does't help. I think have some idea why its getting replaced twice, but the strange thing is I thought + was a 'greedy' operator, so if there was two forward slashes, it wouldn't match just one.