# How to use a number beside a group number in regex replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

The title of the question is not exactly clear but the problem is quite simple.

I match the AssemblyVersion in an AssemblyInfo.cs file and try to replace the version.

Basically the code is similar to :

```
// FileContent is the text content of
// the AssemblyInfo.cs file
var version = new Version(2, 0, 0, 0);
var regex = new Regex(@"^(\s?\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("")([0-9\.]+)(""\)])", RegexOption.Multiline);
var result = regex.Replace(FileContent, "$1" + version + "$3");
```

With this sample, result here equals `$12.0.0.0")]` which is not exactly a good result.

The only way I found to differenciate the `$1` from the version number is to put a space, but it's not what I'm looking for.

How would I be able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `${1}`. There are plenty of similar questions on SO ([Why is "$1" ending up in my Regex.Replace() result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432983/why-is-1-ending-up-in-my-regex-replace-result))