# Notepad++ Regex Replace Capture Groups With Numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

So I have numbers that I'm trying to replace in Notepad++ and I have to tweak both positive values and negative ones, so my search looks like this:

`v (.{0,1})13.500000`

And the replace:

`v $1 10.500000`

Except I don't want the space there between the capture group reference and the other digits, but if I leave the space out, it places nothing (no capture group #110).

How do I "escape" it so that the capture group is separate from the character-literals without inserting an unwanted character?

I could do this as two replacements, but I figured this must be possible, although I can't figure out how to search for it.

Sample source text:

```
v 13.000000 19.0000000 8.000000
v 13.000000 19.0000000 9.000000
v -13.000000 19.0000000 9.000000
v -13.000000 19.0000000 8.000000
```

Desired result:

```
v 10.000000 19.0000000 8.000000
v 10.000000 19.0000000 9.000000
v -10.000000 19.0000000 9.000000
v -10.000000 19.0000000 8.000000
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking for here. Can you provide more examples?

Comment: @JohnKeyes I added a sample source and result, does that help?

Comment: It does, I see @Edurado Escobar has shown you the way.

Comment: @JohnKeyes I guess I made the assumption that the search string was simple enough.  I should know better by now, heh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this replacement:

```
v ${1}10.500000
```

Comment: Ah ha, that did it.  What is this referred to?  No searching on SE or via Google turned up this notation.

Comment: Sorry, **polygenelubricants** explains it in his answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466892/regex-replacement-capture-followed-by-digit

Comment: Bloody hell, why did none of my searching find that post.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I will simply try to capture all in two groups except first digits...

Find what: `(v.+?)\d+(.+$)`
Replace with: `$110$2`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it in **Notepad++**? Here, I get `.000000 19.0000000 8.000000` instead of expected result.

Comment: You know that `$110` means the one hundred and tenth capture group. It does not mean capture group one followed by `10`. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I applaud you for learning about regular expressions and trying to write new answers here, but adding poor quality answers to old questions with accepted answers is not useful. New answers are only useful if they add new information or new insights into solving the problem.

Comment: The \d+ is actually 13 digits that I didn't capture in two groups so,  $1 is first group 10 is for replacing it with 13 numbers that I mentioned it before, and $2 is backreference for second group, how come you ask me so simple questions?

Comment: @Toto,  yes sir, I first examine it then share my answer, as I said it many time that I'm using mobile editor, called,,,, nmm editor

Comment: When you answer a Notepad++ question, please, test your answer with Notepad++. Your answer doesn't work at all in Notepad++.

Comment: I just added photo explanation to my answer, it really does work here in my editor, sorry I'm not PC user, I am using mobile as you can see from my screen images....

Comment: I've no doubts it works with **your** editor, but the question is about Notepad++ and the answers **must** work with it.